# Present UISearchController from button animates keyboard appearance strangely on first presentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I am presenting a `UISearchController` from a search icon on my navigation bar and when the controller is presented the first time the keyboard appears to zoom in from the left side instead of appearing from the bottom. But when presented a second time (and anytime thereafter), it appears correctly with the normal animation.

Any idea why this would happen? Is there a different way I should be presenting the search controller?

I have tried presenting it directly on self (which is a `UITableViewController`) instead of the `UINavigationController` parent with no difference.

Should I just learn to love this and forget about it? :)

Relevant presentation code:

```
// viewDidLoad
UISearchController *searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
        [searchController setDimsBackgroundDuringPresentation:NO];
        [searchController setHidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation:NO];
        [searchController setDelegate:self];
        [searchController setSearchResultsUpdater:self];
        self.searchController = searchController;

# pragma mark - Actions

- (void)search:(id)sender {
    [self.searchController setActive:YES];
}

# pragma mark - UISearchControllerDelegate

- (void)presentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:self.searchController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: try playing with the presentationContext?     self.definesPresentationContext = NO;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried that with no success.

Comment: UISearchController is unfortunately notoriously buggy. I'd suggest potentially delaying setActive until the completion handler of your present call is invoked. That may give UIKit enough time to figure itself out.